# Library source does not match the bytecode for class ServletRequestAttributes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gradle

I'm just trying to build a basic REST API using spring boot and gradle. I've created a custom exception handler though, and when I'm try to access this value:

`((ServletWebRequest) request).getRequest().getRequestURI()`

I get a cannot resolve method error. (Only the .getRequestURI() method is underlined in red)

When I press on getRequest to go to the class, I'm shown the file with this message:

`Library source does not match the bytecode for class ServletRequestAttributes`

[Class with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pP0v.png)

In particular it seems to be a clash between these two:
[Cache Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix3x2.png)

This is my build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc'

    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc'

    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.19.v20190610'


    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core'


//Thanks for using https://jar-download.com

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I tried clearing the gradle caches, adding specific versions to the dependencies and removing them completely. I cannot seem to resolve this.

Comment: Please do no use images for code, logs, errors or any information that is textual.